# What does inconsistent test results mean?

Tags: cross-validation

I'm doing some research on CNN for text classification using tensorflow. When I run my model I get a very high training accuracy (arround 100%). However, on test split I get an inconsistent accuracy results (sometimes 11% and sometimes 90%).

Moreover, I noticed also that the loss in training is decreasing until it reaches small numbers like 0.000499564048368, while in testing it is not and sometimes it gets high values like 70. What does this mean? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Training error << test/resampling error:

- your model is **overfit**

Inconsistent test/resampling error:

- either your **sample size is too small***, or/and
- your models are **unstable**
- Overfitting, model instability, and too small small sample sizes come together.

Papers we wrote on required test sample sizes and measuring model stability:

- [Beleites, C. and Neugebauer, U. and Bocklitz, T. and Krafft, C. and Popp, J.: Sample size planning for classification models. Anal Chim Acta, 2013, 760, 25-33.

  DOI: 10.1016/j.aca.2012.11.007](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aca.2012.11.007)
  [accepted manuscript on arXiv: 1211.1323](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1323)
- [Beleites, C. & Salzer, R.: Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations Anal Bioanal Chem, 2008, 390, 1261-1271.

  DOI: 10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6)